# Is there any advantage to bringing the user in-app for reset password vs in a browser?

Tags: user-expectation, password, reset, password-recovery

Is there any notable difference between bringing the user to a browser to 'reset password' vs bringing them back to the app to do the reset? Considering that this platform exists as an app and as a website? Is it better to just use the browser (so there's only one page to reset the password instead of catering a separate one for the app)?

Comment: Do you have info on how users mix using the app and the website? For example, if there is a sizeable user-base that always (or nearly so) _only_ uses the app, they might be surprised (and justifiably suspicious) if they were taken to a website to reset the password (and _vice versa_ for users who [almost] exclusively use the website). If virtually all your users freely mix the two, it may not matter.

Comment: Is it possible to drop some kind of token so that you know if the user has triggered the password reset from the app or from the website? If so, you could return them to whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Always, always, always keep the reset in the app. I once tested a reset password functionality from inside an app to a browser and the users I was testing with, all of them to a tee, asked "Why is the reset link taking me to the browser?"

If the user forgets the password inside the app, email a reset link, and then the link from the email should bring the user back to the app where they create a new password.